# Powershell - Changing form item properties in a foreach loop dynamically

Tags: loops, powershell, variables, dynamic, nested

I have a collection of items in a form with 12 labels, and I have a list of 12 objects with values I want to assign to each label.  I think I need something with this type of logic:
    ($label1, $label2, etc.)

```
foreach ($i in $objects) {
  $label($i).Content = "$($object[$i].Name)"
}
```

I can't get the first part to resolve to $label1.  I've tried assigning it a new variable with New-Variable, and various combinations of escape characters and parentheses/brackets, but to no avail.  Is there a way to do this, or do I have to re-examine my logic for the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

$i in $objects
is your problem. $i will not be a numeric value, but an object. So it can not be used as an index.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $objects.count; $i++) {
   $label[$i].Content = $objects[$i].Name
}
```

(untested, but the idea should work ;) )

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I don't think we're thinking of the same thing.  The first line in the code block needs to be $label1, not $label[1].  I'm not actually wanting it to be an index, but rather a part of the variable name.  I've found a workaround for now, but I'll keep working on this and update the OP when I get a good solution.

Comment: Ah, now I see. `New-Variable -Name "Label$i" -Value "$objects[$i].Name"` should work fine. But if you want the property .Content in your new variable you will of course have to add it first. This might easier if you could show what the content of $objects is like.